# Featured Image Cetegory Not Shown In WordPress

Tags: images, blog

I am trying to create a post for a new WordPress website, and want to show a thumbnail in my blog for the post. However, the "Featured Image" tab is not there. I have seen the solution to add this code: add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); to my theme file, except it is already there, and there still is no featured image tab.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you've turned off that panel. You can check by clicking on the "three dots" menu (top right of the post editing screen) and selecting **Preferences** at the end of the menu. On the pop-up that appears, select **Panels** and ensure that the **Feature Images** slider is active.

[image: Screenshot of the Preferences->Panels screen]